# SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma 00917. 00000 - "missing comma"

Tags: oracle

When I try and insert the below data I receive the error: SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
INSERT INTO club(member_id, first_name, last_name, join_date, club_name, sea_fresh)
VALUES (club_member_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'John', 'Murphy','TO_DATE('05-OCT-1995','DD-MON-YYYY')', 'SpudWoulds', 'Sea');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'TO_DATE('05-OCT-1995','DD-MON-YYYY')'
```

has too many quotes. Remove the outer ones. (Oracle thinks `'TO_DATE('` is a string, then expects a comma and the next value.)

Answer (score 0):

TO_DATE is an Oracle inbuilt function to convert a string into a date, you should not enclose it within single quotes so **'TO_DATE('05-OCT-1995','DD-MON-YYYY')'** should be written as **TO_DATE('05-OCT-1995','DD-MON-YYYY')**